# Content of wysiwyg editor

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a problem with inserting value to wysiwyg editor when editing item in collection. I have this code, but editor still remain null.

```
 $content = Mage::getModel('news/news')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
                        $fieldset->addField('ContentText', 'editor', array(
                            'name'      => 'content',
                            'label'     => Mage::helper('news')->__('Content'),
                            'title'     => Mage::helper('news')->__('Content'),
                            'style'     => 'height:20em;width:70em;',
                            'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
                            'value'     => $content['content'],
                            'wysiwyg'   => true,
                            'required'  => true,
                        ));
```

when i call

```
die($content['content']);
```

I get my requested value

Comment: check if you don't call `$form->setValues()` later in the code. That will override the value of your field.

Comment: Yes, that's the point - but when I add my editor field after calling '$form->setValues()' it will be the last element in form. Is there a way to set priority to render ?

Comment: Don't add the editor after `$form->setValues()`. Try using `$form->addValues()` instead and make sure that there is no `content` element in the array you pass as a parameter to `addValues`.

Comment: @Marius fancy adding an complete answer here ;)

Comment: @DavidManners. Odd thing...I was just on this question, started to write an answer and your comment popped up. :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments... you can add in your code, after defining the form this

```
$form->setValues(array(...., 'content'=>$content['content']));  
or
$form->addValues(array(...., 'content'=>$content['content']));
```